# How to change the lxpanel language?

Tags: lubuntu, language-support, lxde, lxpanel

i would like to know if its possible to easily change the lxpanel interface language to portuguese for example.

If its not built in feature, where can i start to find the resources for changing it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this in Lubuntu from the Preferences / Language Support application.

If the language of your choice is not already installed, install it using the "Install/Remove Languages..." button.  Then drag it to the top of the list.

Then click the "Apply System-Wide" button.

Now, log out and back in.  Lxpanel and all other menus will be displayed in your selected language.

---Before---

[image]

---After----

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know via cli how to do the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, I do not.

Answer (score 0):

command line:

1. 'locale' [displays current language]
2. 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale' [follow menus in dialogue box]
3. 'reboot'
4. 'locale' [your system should be now in the new language]

Answer (score 0):

To change language for applications from the GUI; following works:

- (Lubuntu) : Preferences; LXQt Settings; Locale
- (Ubuntu ver without a preinstalled "language support" app).
  from Muon Package manager, look for " Language-selector-gnome" and mark for installation.

Then you will have a Language support entry on the menu
From "Language support" install your desired language.

Probably you will need to reboot and reopen "language support" and then it will download and complete the installation of selected language

In any event, previous steps will not change the language of the windows manager LXQt that was selected during the installation